# Javascript string animated from random chars to pre-defined

Tags: javascript

I'm building the animation that will stop on the values defined in `data-final` attributes and will stop sequentially for each char - I expect this code to have different animation duration for each symbol, but they all end simultaneously, though `duration` is set correctly - 1000, 2000, ..., 8000.
How do I stop animation sequentially here?

```js
function count() {
  var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  var numbers = "0123456789"
  var string = numbers + letters;
  var allCounters = document.querySelectorAll(".counter > i");

  allCounters.forEach(function(el) {
    duration = 1000 + Array.from(allCounters).indexOf(el) * 1000;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
    //console.log(duration);            
      if (duration > 0) {
        el.innerText = string.charAt(Math.random() * string.length);
        duration = duration - 50;      
      } else {
        clearInterval(interval);
        el.innerText = el.getAttribute("data-final");
      }
    }, 50);
  });
}

count();

document.addEventListener('click', count)
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron');

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Orbitron;
  
}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
  background: salmon;
}

.counter {
  height: 100%;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

i {
  min-width: 70px;
  text-align: center;
font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="counter">
  <i data-final="0"></i>
  <i data-final="1"></i>
  <i data-final="8"></i>
  <i data-final="2"></i>
  <i data-final="5"></i>
  <i data-final="0"></i>
  <i data-final="0"></i>
  <i data-final="0"></i>
  <i data-final="x"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to define `duration` as a `var` (or `let`, which should be the same since it's a function scope anyway). By not doing so, you made it a global variable that is shared between all iterations of your loop.

This becomes (using `var` here since the rest is using it as well):

```js
function count() {
  var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  var numbers = "0123456789"
  var string = numbers + letters;
  var allCounters = document.querySelectorAll(".counter > i");

  allCounters.forEach(function(el) {
    var duration = 1000 + Array.from(allCounters).indexOf(el) * 1000;        
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      el.innerText = string.charAt(Math.random() * string.length);
      duration = duration - 50;
      if (duration <= 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        el.innerText = el.getAttribute("data-final");
      }
    }, 50);
  });
}

count();

document.addEventListener('click', count)
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron');

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Orbitron;
  
}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
  background: salmon;
}

.counter {
  height: 100%;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

i {
  min-width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="counter">
  <i data-final="0"></i>
  <i data-final="1"></i>
  <i data-final="8"></i>
  <i data-final="2"></i>
  <i data-final="5"></i>
  <i data-final="0"></i>
  <i data-final="0"></i>
  <i data-final="0"></i>
  <i data-final="x"></i>
</div>
```